# Eventually periodic continued fraction implies root of polynomial of degree 2

Tags: number-theory, ergodic-theory

How to prove that every irrational number with eventually periodic continued fraction expansion is a root of a polynomial of degree 2?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_continued_fraction.

Comment: The question in the title doesn't match the question in the body.

Comment: yes you're right, just forget the title please. it's my first question in this website.

Comment: I saw  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_continued_fraction. they answered by "yes" without giving a proof.

Comment: Surely you mean a polynomial with certain type of coefficients.  Otherwise, $p_r(x)=(x-r)^2$ has root $r$, duh! :-)

Comment: Please *edit* the title so it accords with the question.

Comment: PLEASE edit the title.

Comment: Never mind, I did it for you.

Answer (score 3):

This is a classical result.

If you want to prove it yourself start with the case of a constant continued fraction and note that:
\begin{equation}
r=a+\frac{1}{b+\frac{1}{b+\frac{1}{b+\ldots}}}=a+\frac{1}{(b-a)+r}
\end{equation}
Now multiplying both sides by $(b-a)+r$ yields a quadratic expression (with integer coefficients) for $r$.

The general case is similar, and I hope you can do it on your own, using the special case I provided above.